# What is the alternative for ls command in linux?

Tags: bash, command-line, ls, command

How can I list the current directory or any directory path contents without using ls command? Can we do it using echo command?

Comment: found it! " echo * " will do the job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
printf '%s\n' *
```

as a shell command will list the non-hidden files in the current directory, one per line. If there's no non-hidden file, it will display `*` alone except in those shells where that issue has been fixed (csh, tcsh, fish, zsh, bash -O failglob).

```
echo *
```

Will list the non-hidden files separated by space characters except (depending on the shell/echo implementation) when the first file name starts with `-` or file names contain backslash characters.

It's important to note that it's the shell expanding that `*` into the list of files before passing it to the command. You can use any command here like, `head -- *` to display the first few lines (with those `head` implementations that accept several files), `stat -- *`...

I you want to include hidden files:

```
printf '%s\n' .* *
```

(depending on the shell, that will also include `.` and `..`). With `zsh`:

```
printf '%s\n' *(D)
```

Among the other applications (beside shell globs and `ls`) that can list the content of a directory, there's also `find`:

```
find . ! -name . -prune
```

(includes hidden files except `.` and `..`).

On Linux, `lsattr` (lists the Linux extended file attributes):

```
lsattr
lsattr -a # to include hidden files like with ls
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a list of directory contents:
`find . -maxdepth 1`

or for any other dir:
`find <dir> -maxdepth 1`

Comment: Note that it includes hidden files except `..`. `-maxdepth` is a GNU extension (now supported by a few other implementations); the portable/standard equivalent would be: `find . -name . -o -prune` or `find . ! -name . -prune` if you don't care for the `.` entry).